# Xcode (iOS) - Switching Between Storyboards With The Press Of A Button

Tags: ios, button, storyboard, ibaction

This is a very simple question, I want to know how I'd switch between storyboards with the press of a button.  I understand how to get input from a button.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
     //Code goes here
}
```

All I need to know though, is the code that'll allow me to switch between storyboards.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `enum` like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, StoryBordType) {
    StoryBordTypeA = 0,
    StoryBordTypeB,
    StoryBordTypeC
};
```

Then you can define couple of class level properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStoryboard *storyboard;
@property (nonatomic, assign) StoryBordType currentStoryBoard;
```

Finally, implement your button action handler like this:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    switch (self.currentStoryBoard) {
        case StoryBordTypeA:
            self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryBordTypeB" bundle:nil];
            self.currentStoryBoard = StoryBordTypeB;
            break;

        case StoryBordTypeB:
            self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryBordTypeC" bundle:nil];
            self.currentStoryBoard = StoryBordTypeC;
            break;

        case StoryBordTypeC:
            self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryBordTypeA" bundle:nil];
            self.currentStoryBoard = StoryBordTypeA;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```